# Why is my disk full

Tags: opensuse, disk-usage, btrfs

I know that this question is often asked, but I didn't find an answer for my case. I am running openSUSE with one 50 GiB btrfs partition and one 700 GiB part mounted under /var/lib/libvirt

df -h shows me that the 50 GiB partition is full, but `du -sh /*` shows me that the largest folder is /usr with 5 GiB and /var/lib/libvirt.

I have removed all snapshots with snapper and gained 2 GiB with that, but where is the rest of my disk?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that the edifier isn't working. You need to add some edification and it'll start working again. Alternatively put some detail in the question so we've a chance of actually being able to identify an issue.

Comment: @roaima what level of palantier support are you on? All I see in my crystal ball is a pair of burning hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rebooting there was another snapshot with 40 GiB. I removed it and now it works fine

Answer (score 2):

The disk space is not shown as freed (and actually freed) before all file handlers are closed against the big files you deleted. lsof is a handy command in detecting which processes still have the files open, a solution is to restart the processes that have the file handlers open.

`lsof +D /var/lib/libvirt`

would display open files and processes for that matter.

Comment: /var/lib/libvirt is on a seperate disk. I rebooted, so deleted files should be deleted